# add key from array to existing array values in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an array key-value pair. I need to create new array from this key and value pair. for eg

I tried with foreach loop

```
    foreach($array as $key => $val){
// here i m getting key and value i want to combine key and value in single array
    }

Array
(
'146' => Array
    (
        'sam' => Array (
                'dex',
                'max'
        )
    )
'143' => Array
    (
         'tim' => Array (
                'thai',
                'josh'
        )           
    )
 )
```

and the expected output is push key as first element

```
$out = [
    [ 'sam', 'dex', 'max'],
    [  'tim','thai', 'josh']
];
```

Comment: Will it always just be 2 levels deep?

Comment: @vivek_23 nope. just for eg I have written

Comment: Where are the 146 and 143 gone? shouldn't it be [146,sam,dex,max],[... ?

Comment: @sGig So, it's just 2 levels deep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array-merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) as:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val)
    $out[] = array_merge([$key], $val);
```

Notice that in your example you also have another level of keys ("146", "143") -> you need to remove it before using this code.

**Edited**:

```
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $key = key($val);
    $out[] = array_merge([$key], $val[$key]);
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/6Lpa2)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```php
$output = [];
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $data = $val;
    array_unshift($data, $key);
    $output[] = $data;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this before posting, its not as per expected o/p

Comment: @sGig - you indicated you wanted to combine `$key` and `$val` from your example `foreach` loop into a single array - this does that (and so does @dWinder's answer)

Answer (score 0):

- So, we need to flatten the array for each key in your array.
- We make a function which recursively calls the further deep arrays and we collect all these results in a new array which is passed as a second parameter.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$arr = Array(
'146' => Array
    (
        'sam' => Array (
                'dex',
                'max'
        )
    ),
'143' => Array
    (
         'tim' => Array (
                'thai',
                'josh'
        )           
    )
 );


$result = [];

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $flat_data = [];
    flattenArray($value,$flat_data);
    $result[] = $flat_data;
}


function flattenArray($data,&$flat_data){
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)){
            $flat_data[] = $key;
            flattenArray($value,$flat_data);
        }else{
            $flat_data[] = $value;
        }   
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/bX9R3

- Since, we are passing a new array to collect the results as second parameter, this would perform better than returning an array of results on each function call and then doing an array merge(which would have made a bit inefficient).
- This would work independent of the depth of levels.